# SQL issue : I want to show results related to each category

Tags: php, sql

I don't know how to write SQL code.

There are two tables:

**Categories** :(category_id, category_name)
**Products:** (product_id, category_id, product_name)

```
aaa category (example.com/aaa)
bbb category (example.com/bbb) 
ccc category (example.com/ccc)
ddd category (example.com/ddd)
eee category (example.com/eee)
```

If I click example.com/aaa, I want to show only products related to aaa category.

I tried something like this but I cannot complete it at all!!!

```
select *
from categories AS c,products AS p
where c.category_id=p.category_id
```

If I use above code, all products are showing every category.

Too difficult.

Thank you in advance, guys!

Comment: You just need to add a second condition in the WHERE clause: `where c.category_id=p.category_id and c.category_name = 'aaa'`. But it's better to use the JOIN syntax as shown in IllegalPigeons [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37510357/5563083).

Answer (score 0):

You need a join. Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products p
JOIN categories c ON p.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE c.category_name = "aaa"
```